# Nested div with height 100% with sticky footer

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZC2A/

I'm trying to get my white wrapper div to have a height of 100% without messing up my sticky footer. I've tried removing height: auto !important so my wrapper div will extend 100%, but that messes up my sticky footer. It also causes the footer to overlap the pictures when resizing. Any help is appreciated thank you.

```
.supercontainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  }
.wrapper {
  border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-left: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working copy of your fiddle. Please do not use display:table

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZC2A/6/)

Your code needs some site architecture. And as far as the wrapper overlapping your footer, if you mean going under it when you scroll, well, it has to go somewhere. You did want it fixed after all.

When making a footer fixed (sticky) you have to understand the page will reach its bottom and the footer will be there blocking it. SO you give the page a margin-bottom for the size of the footer to force that page bottom up like so

```
.wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help LOTUSMS, I'm trying to get the wrapper div to expand to 100% though, and I don't see that in your demo.

Comment: It does, but remember, the footer being fixed is blocking the view. The bottom of the page is the bottom of the page. But I do have your solution. BRB